# If/else в pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, логические-выражения

Есть:

```
data = pd.read_csv('somedata.csv')
```

Там есть две колонки 'settings' и 'config' в которых есть только True/False (string). Я знаю, что с loc я могу обратится к определенным строкам

```
data.loc[: , ['settings']
```

Теперь такой вопрос, могу ли я написать что-то вроде:

```
#псевдокод
if(data.loc[: , ['settings'] == "True"):
    print("YES")
else:
    print("No")
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите проверить что **все** значения в столбце равны `"True"`:

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
  settings config
0     True   cfg1
1     True   cfg2
2     True   cfg3

In [5]: df.dtypes
Out[5]:
settings    object
config      object
dtype: object

In [6]: if (df["settings"] == "True").all():
   ...:     print("YES")
   ...: else:
   ...:     print("No")
   ...:
YES
```

__

добавим строку с `"False"`:

```
In [8]: df.loc[3] = ["False", "cfg4"]

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
  settings config
0     True   cfg1
1     True   cfg2
2     True   cfg3
3    False   cfg4

In [10]: if (df["settings"] == "True").all():
    ...:     print("YES")
    ...: else:
    ...:     print("No")
    ...:
No
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!